# Simple TypeScript Testing with Chutzpah not Working

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

I'm trying to run the most basic of `TypeScript` tests using `Jasmine` and `Chutzpah` and I just can't get it to work. Here is the source file:

```
class Simple {
    public easyTest() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Here is the spec:

```
/// <reference path="../../../scripts/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../src/typescript/classSimple.ts" />
describe("Simple Calculations", () => {
    it("should return true", () => {
        var simpl = new Simple();
        expect(simpl.easyTest()).toBe(5);
    });
});
```

Here is my `chutzpah.json` file:

```
{
    "RootReferencePathMode": "SettingsFileDirectory",
    "Framework": "jasmine",
    "Compile": {
        "Mode": "External",
        "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
        "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ]
    },
    "References": [        
        { "Path": "../../../src/typescript/classSimple.ts" }        
    ],
    "Tests": [
        { "Path": "simpleSpec.ts" }
    ],
    "EnableTracing": true
}
```

Here is the folder structure

```
TestProject.sln
-src
--typescript
---classSimple.ts
-tests
--jasmine
---typescript
----chutzpah.json
----simpleSpec.ts
```

This VS.NET project is set to compile `TypeScript` upon save and I'm physically looking at the transpiled `JavaScript` output: `classSimple.js` in the exact same directory next to `classSimple.ts`. Yet when I run the spec using `Chutzpah` I get the following:

> Message:Chutzpah run started in mode Execution with parallelism set to
>   4 Message:Building test context for
>   C:\dev\TestProject\tests\jasmine\typescript\simpleSpec.ts
>   Message:Building test context for
>   'C:\dev\TestProject\tests\jasmine\typescript\simpleSpec.ts'
>   Message:Test file
>   c:\dev\TestProject\tests\jasmine\typescript\simplespec.ts matched test
>   file path from settings file Message:Investigating reference file path
>   '../../../src/typescript/classSimple.ts' Message:Added file
>   'C:\dev\TestProject\src\typescript\classSimple.ts' to referenced
>   files. Local: True, IncludeInTestHarness: True Message:Processing
>   referenced file 'C:\dev\TestProject\src\typescript\classSimple.ts' for
>   expanded references Message:Added framework dependency
>   'C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\mfv4e3ra.luv\TestFiles\jasmine\v2\jasmine_favicon.png' to referenced files Message:Added framework dependency
>   'C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\mfv4e3ra.luv\TestFiles\jasmine\v2\boot.js'
>   to referenced files Message:Added framework dependency
>   'C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\mfv4e3ra.luv\TestFiles\jasmine\v2\jasmine-html.js'
>   to referenced files Message:Added framework dependency
>   'C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\mfv4e3ra.luv\TestFiles\jasmine\v2\jasmine.js'
>   to referenced files Message:Added framework dependency
>   'C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\mfv4e3ra.luv\TestFiles\jasmine\v2\jasmine.css'
>   to referenced files Message:Added framework dependency
>   'C:\Users\myself\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions\mfv4e3ra.luv\TestFiles\chutzpah_boot.js'
>   to referenced files Message:Finished building test context for
>   C:\dev\TestProject\tests\jasmine\typescript\simpleSpec.ts Error: 0 :
>   Time:22:47:48.6888513; Thread:23; Message:Can't find location for
>   generated path on C:\dev\TestProject\src\typescript\classSimple.ts
>   Warning: 0 : Time:22:47:48.6978503; Thread:23; Message:Chutzpah
>   determined generated .js files are missing but the compile mode is
>   External so Chutzpah can't compile them. Test results may be wrong.
>   Information: 0 : Time:22:47:48.7038522; Thread:23; Message:Found
>   generated path for
>   C:\dev\TestProject\tests\jasmine\typescript\simpleSpec.ts at
>   c:\dev\TestProject\tests\jasmine\typescript\simpleSpec.js Error: 0 :
>   Time:22:47:48.7088508; Thread:23; Message:Couldn't find generated path
>   for C:\dev\TestProject\src\typescript\classSimple.ts at

And that's it - it just cuts off on the end and nothing happens. The thing is, I see the .`js` files **exactly** in the location stated within the trace above, but Chutzpah is claiming *Couldn't find generated path for...*

This is as simple as it gets for unit testing. I know the tests work independently of the `.ts` files because if I run just the `.js` files the tests pass.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for posting the very detailed repro. You are hitting an issue I have seen a couple times. Since your chutzpah.json is nested in your test folder you need to specify the folder path mapping that chutzpah should use for determining how to map from source to output folder. To do this just change your chutzpah.json to:

```
{
    "RootReferencePathMode": "SettingsFileDirectory",
    "Framework": "jasmine",
    "Compile": {
        "Mode": "External",
        "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
        "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ],
        "Paths": [
            { "SourcePath": "../../../", "OutputPath": "../../../"}
        ]
    },
    "References": [        
        { "Path": "../../../src/typescript/classSimple.ts" }        
    ],
    "Tests": [
        { "Path": "simpleSpec.ts" }
    ],
    "EnableTracing": true,
    "TraceFilePath": "trace.txt"
}
```

The other workaround would be to just place the chutzpah.json at the root of your project.

I need to look into making Chutzpah better to avoid this. I think I will look at letting chutzpah in this situation just assume the file is co-located to avoid this common pitfall.

Comment: I committed a change to make sure people in the future won't hit this issue: https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/commit/9328f3d5f546cecc0ebf8f010b455519324c3de8

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to investigate and push that update to GitHub. I obviously did not get that setting in place.

Answer (score 0):

Google led me here for a similar issue:

Some new tests in my Chutzpah project are written in TypeScript and compiled into a single `outfile`:

**tsconfig.json**

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "none",
    "outFile": "./Tests/mytests-ts.js",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
```

Chutzpah couldn't find the `*.ts` files

```
Chutzpah Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Couldn't find generated path for D:\Code\ChutzpahProject\Scripts\DateServiceMock.ts
```

until I used the `Paths` option:

**chutzpah.json**

```
  "Compile": {
    "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
    "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ],
    "Executable": "build-ts.cmd",
    "Paths": [
      { "OutputPath": "Tests/mytests-tests-ts.js" }
    ]
  },
```

This feels like it could have been a comment to @matthew-manela's answer...I think.